# In ECDSA, why is (r,−s mod n) complementary to (r, s)?

Tags: ecdsa, transaction-malleability

I am trying to find resources in previous malleability posts, but couldn't find derivations/proofs of this fact or how the exact low-s value is derived. Any pointers would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ECDSA signatures are pairs (r,s) such that *r = x(m/s*G + r/s*P) mod n*, where *P* is the public key and *m* is the message digest. *x()* in that equation means "the X coordinate of".

In that equation, if you substitute *s = -s'*, you get *r = x(m/(-s')*G + r/(-s)*P) mod n*, or *r = x(-(m/s'*G + r/s'*P))*.

However, it is true that for any point *Q*, *x(Q) = x(-Q)*, as negating a point only affects the Y coordinate. Thus, *r = x(m/s'*G + r/s'*P) mod n*, or *(r,s')* is valid signature whenever *(r,s)* is.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand negating a scalar over ff, but not why that negated scalar * point will result in a point with the same x-coord as scalar * point.

Comment: @JamesC. That follows from the group law definition, which says that `(x,y) + (x,-y) = 0`. This can be rearranged to `(x,-y) = 0 - (x,y) = -(x,y)`. There isn't any particularly deep insight here, it's just how elliptic curve point addition is defined.